# I have a c# WinUI 3 desktop application (VS 2019) - right align text in a datagrid cell

Tags: windows, datagrid, desktop-application, winui-3, right-align

Using a datagrid.  I would like to right align certain columns.  The way I tried it below does not work.  Does anyone know the correct way?  Thanks a lot.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="Results_DataGrid"  
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                       CanUserSortColumns="False"
                       AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"
                       BorderBrush="#005986"
                       BorderThickness="2 2 2 2"
                       Margin="3 10 3 5"
                       PointerReleased="Results_DataGrid_PointerReleased">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Jan"
                        Width="SizeToHeader"
                        Binding="{Binding Jan}"
                        FontSize="11"
                        Foreground="Black" 
                        >
                    **<controls:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        </Style>
                    </controls:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>**
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ElementStyle` in the `DataGridTextColumn` targets a `TextBlock`.

```xml
<controls:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

I also can use the `CellStyle` for this.

```xml
<controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```